# How to mock private members?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, restsharp

I have a service to work with some API. This API requires authorization, so I've decided to provide configuration model to service constructor, which contains auth info. Then constructor initializes `RestClient` with provided token.

```
client = new RestClient(config.Value.BaseUrl)
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(config.Value.Username, config.Value.Token)
};
```

Now I am trying to implement tests over this service and ran into a problem: I can not mock this `RestClient` because it is private.
Is there a way to solve this problem or I'll have to provide `RestClient` through constructor?

Comment: pass every dependency that you would like to test from outside into the class. The containing field can still be private but this way you can also pass a mock inside it. ps. every time you read `foo = new` inside a method or contructor, it is an indicator that you might run into problems when trying to test it

Comment: In order to support mocking you have use either constructor or property dependency injection.